# Why doesn't the Scala compiler accept this lambda as a parameter?

Tags: scala, generics, lambda

Suppose I have an interface for a `Thing`:

```
abstract class Thing[A](a_thing: A) {
  def thingA = a_thing
}
```

and I implement that `Thing` as follows:

```
class SpecificThing(a: String) extends Thing[String](a)
```

Furthermore, suppose I have a function that takes a `Thing` and a lambda that does something to that `Thing` as parameters:

```
def doSomething[A](fn: Thing[A] => A, t: Thing[A]) : A = fn(t)
```

Now, let's use this stuff:

```
val st = new SpecificThing("hi")
val fn1: (Thing[String]) => String = (t: Thing[String]) => { t.thingA }
println(doSomething(fn1, st))
```

This prints `hi`.  So far, so good.  But I'm lazy, and I don't like typing so much, so I change my program to the following:

```
type MyThing = Thing[String]
val st = new SpecificThing("hi")
val fn2: (MyThing) => String = (t: MyThing) => { t.thingA }
println(doSomething(fn2, st))
```

and this also prints `hi`.  Fabulous!  The compiler can tell that a `SpecificThing` is both a `Thing[String]` and a `MyThing`.  But what about this case?

```
val st = new SpecificThing("hi")
val fn3: (SpecificThing) => String = (t: SpecificThing) => { t.thingA }
println(doSomething(fn3, st))
```

Now I get:

```
Error:(14, 23) type mismatch;
 found   : SpecificThing => String
 required: Thing[?] => ?
  println(doSomething(fn3, st))
                      ^
```

What's going on?  What's a `Thing[?]`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`f3` isn't a `Thing[String] => String`, it's a `SpecificThing => String`. For an example of why they couldn't be compatible:

```
class SpecificThing2 extends Thing[String] {
  def thingB = 2.0
}
val f4: SpecificThing2 => String = {
  st: SpecificThing2 => f"%f${st.thingB / 3.0}"
}
val t = new Thing[String]("haha"){}
f4(t) // would be an error when f4 tried to access t.thingB
```

More formally, `Function1` is *contravariant* in its first type parameter, `Function1[-T, +R]`.

A `Thing[?]` is what it looks like; it's a `Thing[X]` for some unknown type `X`. The compiler is gamely trying to infer what the type `A` should be, but it can't make it work: it needs a `Thing[A] => A` for some (unknown-to-it) type `A`, and you're passing it a `SpecificThing => String`; that's the error.